# Seleniumvs Java Applet

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I'm making a bot with selenium and IE to automatize some tasks. I'm now facing a problem that I don't know how to solve : there is a Java Applet and I need to click in a button that is inside this Applet, how could I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example for python , i have removed the Java one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.get("http://localhost")
wd.execute_script("function()")
```

Comment: But this is Java and I'm programming in Python

Comment: And how can i find the availables fields into a Java Applet if i cannot use DEM like in HTML?

Comment: what do you mean by 'DEM like in HTML'

Comment: The DOM, sorry. With it I can easily find the name of the differents buttons and fields in a HTML document. I would like to find the name of the button that I have to click in the Java Applet

Comment: If you are using Chrome then it is easy with https://developer.chrome.com/devtools. Just press F12 from you webpage and you can easily locate the web element that are interested